# Unbinding events on scrollout - recommended?

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, marionette, backbone-views, backbone-events

My site is built on Backbone. It has a feed based UI, which means there are often a large amount of content displayed in a feed. Roughly, about 30 events bind to each item.

It gets sluggish after scrolling down a couple of pages.

Does it make sense to unbind the items that has been scrolled out, and bind again when they are scrolled in?

What might be causing the slowness?

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to say whether the sluggishness is because of event handlers, or simply because the browser cannot handle the sheer amount of DOM nodes on the page, or any other reason.

Here's a quick solution for undelegating events for views which are not in the current viewport. It's not exactly production-ready, but should help you with testing whether the event handlers are the cause of the performance problem.

([Working JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/uysZt/), also check the browser console)

```
var View = Backbone.View.extend({

  onScroll: function() {

    var wasInView = this.isInView;
    var isInView = this.checkIsInView();

    if(wasInView === true) {
      if(!isInView) {
         this.undelegateEvents(); 
      }
    } 
    else if(wasInView === false) {
      if(isInView) {
        this.delegateEvents();
      }
    }
    else {
      //first pass
      if(!isInView) {
        this.undelegateEvents();
      }
    }

    this.isInView = isInView;
  },

  checkIsInView: function() {
    var $el = this.$el,
        top = $el.offset().top,
        bottom = top + $el.height(),
        windowTop = $(window).scrollTop(),
        windowBottom = windowTop + $(window).height();

    return ((bottom <= windowBottom) && (top >= windowTop));
  },

  render: function () {

    //rendering code here...

    if(!this.lazyScroll) {
      //wait for scroll events to stop before triggering scroll handler
      this.lazyScroll = _.debounce(_.bind(this.onScroll, this), 50);
      $(window).bind('scroll', this.lazyScroll)
               .bind('resize', this.lazyScroll); 
    }

    return this;
  },

  remove: function() {
    if(this.lazyScroll) {
      $(window).unbind('scroll', this.lazyScroll)
               .unbind('resize', this.lazyScroll); 
      delete this.lazyScroll;
    }
    Backbone.View.prototype.remove.apply(this, arguments);
  }
});
```

Comment: thanks @fencliff! i will test it out and get back to you. thanks a million again :)

Comment: i implemented a version of this after testing! turns out that it did not really help performance at the start, but prevented excessive memory issues as you scrolled.